# XML::LibXML: Speedquestion

Tags: xml, perl, performance

This script takes about 50 minutes, ( filesize: 22,3 MiB, cpu: atom ).
Is this normal (the 50 minutes)?
Could I tweak the script, to make it faster?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use XML::LibXML;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:SQLite:dbname=$db", undef, undef, $options );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO $table ( id, titel, ... ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ... )" );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->load_xml( location => $file );
my @nodes = $doc->findnodes( '//Mediathek/Filme' );

my @keys = qw( Id Titel ... );

for my $node ( @nodes ) {
    my @nodes = $node->findnodes( './*' );
    my %hash;
    @hash{@keys} = ();
    for my $node ( @nodes ) {
        $hash{$node->nodeName} = $node->textContent;
    }
    $sth->execute( @hash{@keys} );
}
```

Comment: What does the [profiler](http://p3rl.org/Devel::NYTProf#SYNOPSIS) say where the bottleneck is?

Comment: He says, that `_findnodes` takes more than 96% of the time (44884 calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Ashley is right when pointing to the transactions and the associated costly IO.

As for the XML part, given the input doc size of 22 MB, you're going to need about 200 MB of memory but processing should be reasonably fast, in the range of seconds, not minutes.

One thing that looks inefficient is your whole-doc-scan XPath expression. Can `Mediathek/Filme` really appear anywhere in the document? Or is it rather something like `/Archiv/Mediathek/Filme`? Using `//` is inefficient unless the engine optimizes this expression (which XML::LibXML doesn't do, as far as I know).

Another thing is that you could use `$node->getChildElements` instead of `$node->findnodes("*")` (no need to write `./*`), but I don't think it'll matter much.

Comment: Using `childNodes` it took about one and a half minutes (I didn't find `getChildElements`).

Comment: @sid_com - You're right, it's `childNodes` (`getChildElements` is from XOM/Java). From my testing, `getChildrenByLocalName('*')` and `getChildrenByTagNameNS('', '*')` should be a little faster than `childNodes`, which also returns (whitespace) text nodes you don't care about. You could also use `nonBlankChildNodes`. The best is to use one of the two methods returning only elements as this is what you're interested in here.

Answer (score 1):

XML::LibXML is *very* fast. And so is SQLite *if* you batch `INSERT`s. SQLite write activity is limited by spin speed as part of its guarantee to not write broken data. So the speed gain you're looking for is probably in a transaction. Batch up many/all of your `INSERT`s—limiting factor to size of batches will be RAM I think—before committing. The [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) docs describe to do this.

Again, this is untested, but it’s good to learn transactions even if I’m wrong. :P

Comment: As @Ashley suggests, you're probably running in to limits in terms of the number of transactions you can perform per second because each transaction results in one or more `fsync(2)` calls, which are doggedly slow (and for good reason).

Comment: I don't no if this matters regarding your suggestion - I am using `PRAGMA cache_size = 400000` and `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF`

Answer (score 1):

You could try a couple of things.

1. Given you are effectively streaming your XML, could you re-implement it using a SAX Processor? - XML::SAX::ExpatXS is blindingly fast and uses the standard SAX interfaces.
2. You could consider using a bulk insert for your SQL, inserting multiple rows in a single statement, this will limit the number of index rebuilds.